# Check data is the same after restore SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I've backed up, transferred to another location and restored a database. Is there anyway to check that the data is the exact same?

Would I be best using the CHECKSUM and then the VERIFYONLY method?

Thanks.

Comment: Oops sorry, I always forget that. It's SSMS 2008r2

Comment: First, it's SQL Server 2008 R2. Second, the database will definitely *not* be the same as it was before the restore, unless nothing was written to it since the last backup. Are you trying to ask something else?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas agree but the question isn't clear, it will be closed rather quickly

Comment: Depends on what type of backup you made and what you included in that backup. So, the most accurate answer is: **possibly**.

Comment: Is there anyway to check that the data is the exact same ... as what? The parent DB? Do you have reason to believe it wouldn't be? Or are you wanting to verify there is no corruption?

Answer (score 0):

First, CHECKSUM and VERIFYONLY do not do what you think they do.  Backing up with CHECKSUM merely verifies that the page checksums (if there and valid) are valid when writing the backup file.  VERIFYONLY only verifies that the backup file is complete and readable.

But none of this will protect you from corruption in the source database, it is entirely possible for there to be corrupt pages, have them backed up and then restore them into the new database.

What and why are you trying to do the verificaton?  You can do row counts for each table and compare that way.  RedGate has a comparison tool (paid, but with a trial) that can compare and display the differences.